# Como salvar caminho da uma foto tirada da câmera do celular em Path ou String

Tags: android, imagem

Preciso pegar o caminho que foi salvo a imagem e salvar ele para que sempre que eu inicie o app aparece a imagem em uma ImageView. meu codigo é esse

```
 public void onClickCamera(View v){
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");        
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);}}
```

Comment: Recomendo dar uma olhada em disk storage. Segue um link com exemplos: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certa vez eu passei pelo mesmo obstáculo, buscando um pouco encontrei um código no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327213/getting-path-of-captured-image-in-android-using-camera-intent) que resolveu meu problema e acredito que resolva o seu também:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        knop.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);


        // Chame este método pra obter a URI da imagem
        Uri uri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);

        // Em seguida chame este método para obter o caminho do arquivo
        File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(uri));

        System.out.println(file.getPath());
    }  
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    return cursor.getString(idx); 
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado eu tava tendo muita dificuldade nessa parte!

Answer (score 1):

@Guilherme você executou seu código de um celular Samsung? Porque não sei se são em todos mas em alguns celulares samsung ocorre um bug dizendo que `data` do método `onActivityResult` retorna null. Vou mostrar como se faz para obter o URI da foto que acabou de ser retirada com base no código que o google disponibiliza em: [Gui da API do Android para Câmera](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents)

```
/**
  * (ISTO é uma variável de instância) Contem o caminho e o nome do arquivo onde desejamos salvar a imagem. 
  * Usado principalmente para iniciar uma Intent.Action_View com esta URI. (GalleryApp)
  */
private Uri uriImagem = null;

public void onClickCamera(View v){
    // Cria uma intent para capturar uma imagem e retorna o controle para quem o chamou (NAO PRECISA DECLARAR PERMISSAO NO MANIFESTO PARA ACESSAR A CAMERA POIS O FAZEMOS VIA INTENT).
    Intent intent = new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    // Cria um arquivo para salvar a imagem.
    uriImagem = ProcessaImagens.getOutputMediaFileUri( ProcessaImagens.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, getActivity().getApplicationContext() );
    // Passa para intent um objeto URI contendo o caminho e o nome do arquivo onde desejamos salvar a imagem. Pegaremos atraves do parametro data do metodo onActivityResult().
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriImagem );
    // Inicia a intent para captura de imagem e espera pelo resultado.
    startActivityForResult( intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE );
}
```

A classe [ProcessaImagens](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4wa6um5nwyi4r0/ProcessaImagens.java) foi uma classe que eu fiz e irei estar compartilhando com todos. Podem utilizar esta classe a vontade. Ela tem um método de compactar imagem muito bom, caso queira salvar imagens no banco de dados. No seu método`onActivityResult` faça isso:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
    // Se finalizou a activity em startForActivityResult.
    if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
        if ( requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE ) {
            String imagemPath = uriImagem.getPath();
            // Vou compactar a imagem, leia o javadoc do médoto e verá que ela retorna tanto um bitmap como um array de bytes.
            List<Object> imagemCompactada = ProcessaImagens.compactarImagem( uriImagem.getPath() );
            Bitmap imagemBitmap = (Bitmap) imagemCompactada.get( 0 );
            byte[] imagemBytes = (byte[]) imagemCompactada.get( 1 );

        }
    }
    // Se cancelou a activity em startForActivityResult.
    else if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED ) {
        if ( requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE ) {
            // Usuario cancelou a captura da imagem.
            Log.d( getTag(), "Captura de imagem CANCELADA!" );
        }
    }
    // Se ocorreu algum erro na activity em startForActivityResult.
    else {
        // Captura da imagem falhou, avisa ao usuario.
        Toast.makeText( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "FALHA! A captura da imagem falhou!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        Log.e( getTag(), "FALHA! A captura da imagem falhou!" );
    }
}
```

Observe que eu usei `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` porque estou obtendo o contexto a partir de um Fragment e não de uma Activity. Acredito que com este método você possa ter o que quer. É só fazer as alterações necessárias como a forma de obter contexto. A forma de obter a TAG para exibir em logs etc.

Comment: Fala Lucas! Sua classe vem me ajudando bastante. Mas surgiu a necessidade de obter um bitmap miniatura, e então estou tentando usar um dos métodos de sua classe, o getMiniaturaImagem, como vc disse ele não pode ser executado na UI, estou tentando sem sucesso da seguinte forma:new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        imagemBitmap = (Bitmap) ProcessaImagens.getMiniaturaImagem(getContentResolver(), uriImagem.getPath(), resultCode);
                    }
                }).start();

Comment: Ele dá esse erro:java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=null} 
to activity {br.com.singlepoint.crm.mobile/br.com.singlepoint.crm.mobile.activity.ChecklistActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown URL: content://media/external/images/media/-1?blocking=1&orig_id=-1&group_id=0

Comment: Tem como você fazer uma nova pergunta e postar partes do seu código para melhor visualização? Aí você me manda o link da sua pergunta aqui para eu acompanhar e tentar ajudar. Por comentário fica mais difícil. Aguardo sua resposta.

Comment: Se puder ajudar eu agradeço muito cara: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104594/gerando-bitmap-de-foto-tirada

Comment: Gostaria da classe ProcessaImagens, o link do Lucas está offline :/