# Gerando Bitmap de foto tirada

Tags: android, bitmap

Estou tentando gerar um bitmap de uma foto tirada:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            // para usar fragment getActivity().getApplicationContext()
            uriImagem = ProcessImages.getOutputMediaFileUri(ProcessImages.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, ChecklistActivity.this);

            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriImagem);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);       
        };
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
Log.i("uriImagemNova", uriImagem.getPath());
    if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            new CarregaMiniaturaAsyncTask().execute();
        }
}

private class CarregaMiniaturaAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // Cria um novo cursor para obter o caminho do arquivo da imagem e sua miniatura.
        Cursor myCursor = null;

        // As colunas que queremos retornar.
        String[] projectionImage = {
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION};
        // Ira organizar a consulta por data em ordem decrescente.
        String imageSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC";

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        // Consulta as imagens armazenadas no sistema de arquivos.
        myCursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projectionImage, null, null, imageSort);

        long imageId = 0l; // Armazena o id da imagem.
        String imagePath = null; // Armazena o caminho para o arquivo da imagem.
        long imageDataTaken = 0l; // Armazena a data em que a imagem foi capturada da camera.
        long imageDataAdded = 0l; // Armazena a data em que a imagem foi adicionada ao MediaStore.
        int imageOrientation = 0; // Armazena a orientacao da imagem.

        // Obtem os dados da imagem
        try {
            myCursor.moveToFirst();
            imageId = myCursor.getLong(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID));
            imagePath = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
            imageDataTaken = myCursor.getLong(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN));
            imageDataAdded = myCursor.getLong(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED));
            imageOrientation = myCursor.getInt(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION));

            Log.d("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "Imagem id.: " + imageId);
            Log.d("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "Imagem path.: " + imagePath);
            Log.d("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "Imagem data taken.: " + imageDataTaken);
            Log.d("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "Imagem data added.: " + imageDataAdded);
            Log.d("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "Imagem Orientation.: " + imageOrientation);

            // Obtem o URI da imagem em tamanho real para ser utilizado na visualizacao da imagem caso clique na miniatura.
            //uriImagem = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(imageId));
            Log.d("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "Imagem uri.: " + uriImagem.getPath());

            // Armazena o id da imagem para ser utilizado no recarregamento da imagem ao voltar da galeria do Android (Gallery App).
            long imagemId = imageId;

            List<Object> imagemCompactada = ProcessImages.compactarImagem(uriImagem.getPath());
            imagemBitmap = (Bitmap) imagemCompactada.get(0);
            byte[] imagemBytes = (byte[]) imagemCompactada.get(1);
            encoded = Base64.encodeBytes(imagemBytes, Base64.DONT_BREAK_LINES | Base64.URL_SAFE);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "A coluna nao existe", e);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "Voce tentou acessar uma localizacao menor que zero ou maior que o tamanho da lista.", e);
        } finally {
            myCursor.close();
        }

        return ProcessImages.getMiniaturaImagem(contentResolver, uriImagem.getPath(), imageId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        imagemBitmap = (Bitmap) result;
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(imagemBitmap);
    }
}
```

O bitmap é gerado com a última foto da galeria pública, e não com a foto que é tirada da câmera e armazenada na pasta do aplicativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao que tudo indica, o cursor só consegue obter dados da galeria pública do android. O que estou tentando fazer agora, é deixar as fotos que ficam na pasta do aplicativo, serem visíveis/indexados no álbum público, assim como acontece com o whatsapp. Alguém sabe a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Diga exatamente qual linha deu erro.

Comment: Desculpe a demora, coloquei uma imagem com o erro na pergunta. Provavelmente estou errando algum argumento no getMiniaturaImagem, ou não estou sabendo chamá-lo, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como observado nos comentários da minha primeira resposta, ela está incorreta, não funciona corretamente em todos os dispositivos. Poderia ter excluído mas vou deixá-la como forma de consulta e entendimento.

Uma nova solução que descobri é a seguinte:

OBS: Não coloquei acento nas palavras dos comentários do código.

```
private Uri fileImageUri; // Variavel de instancia onde sera salvo o novo arquivo de imagem

// Chame este metodo para capturar a foto
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    // Cria a intent para capturar a imagem da camera e retorna o controle para o chamador.
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Aqui nos usamos a classe ProcessaImagens para criar um Arquivo (Para saber sobre a criacao do arquivo, veja o codigo da classe)
    fileImageUri = ProcessaImagens.getOutputMediaFileUri(ProcessaImagens.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, getApplicationContext());
    // Passamos a URI desse novo arquivo para a Intent, dizendo que queremos salvar a nova imagem nele.
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileImageUri);
    // Inicia a intent para captura da imagem e espera pelo resultado no metodo: "onActivityResult"
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Se finalizou a activity em startForActivityResult.
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            processImageCaptured(); // Este metodo ira processar a imagem nesta Activity/Fragment
        }
    }
    // Se cancelou a activity em startForActivityResult.
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            // Usuário cancelou a captura da imagem
        }
    }
    // Se um erro ocorreu na activity em startForActivityResult.
    else {
        // Captura da imagem falhou, avisa ao usuario.
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.fail_activity_take_image), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Para evitar erros com mudancas de orientacao do dispositivo, entre outros, salve o valor da URI no Bundle
    // Recupere o valor da URI em onCreate ou onRestoreInstanceState.
    outState.putParcelable(FILE_IMAGE_URI, fileImageUri); // FILE_IMAGE_URI e uma constante qualquer apenas para guardar o valor
}

private void processImageCaptured() {
    // PRESTE ATENCAO: CHAME APENAS ESTE METODO SE QUISER QUE SUA IMAGEM SEJA ARMAZENA NO PROVEDOR DE CONTEUDO DO SISTEMA
    // E SEJA EXIBIDA NA GALERIA DO ANDROID E OUTROS APPS. LEIA O JAVADOC DO METODO PARA ENTENDER MELHOR.
    galleryAddPic(); 

    // Uma Lista contendo o objeto Bitmap compactado na primeira posicao (0) e seu array de bytes na segunda posicao (1).
    List<Object> image = ProcessaImagens.compactarImagem(fileImageUri.getPath());

    // FACA ALGUMA COISA COM SUA IMAGEM.
}

/**
 * Chame scanner de mídia do sistema para adicionar sua foto ao banco de dados do Provedor de Media,
 * Tornando-o disponível no aplicativo Gallery Android e outros aplicativos.
 */
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(fileImageUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Acredito que com esta nova codificação, irá funcionar em todos os dispositivos. Lembrando que desse jeito a foto fica salva em uma pasta com o nome do seu aplicativo, dentro da pasta "Pictures" do Android. Ela pode ser compartilhada entre aplicações. Para saber mais sobre a criação da pasta/arquivo que será criado as imagens, veja internamente o método responsável dentro da classe `ProcessaImagens`.

Comment: Muito bom, está funcionando agora. No entanto, tem um detalhe, que após tirar a foto e carregar o bitmap em um imageview, em tamanho MINI_KIND por exemplo, ele fica pequeno, mas ao minimizar o app ou desligar a tela, quando volta, o bitmap está grande. Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: @Morfina sinceramente não sei o que pode ser, isso só acontece com o tipo MINI_KIND? Tentou o outro tipo? Estranho isso.

Comment: Se a resposta correta é essa, marque como correta para ajudar e facilitar as buscas de outras pessoas aqui no StackOverflow.

Comment: Então, com o MICRO_KIND parece ocorrer o inverso. Ao voltar no app, ele fica menor do que estava

Comment: Não sei o que pode ser. Vou tentar procurar depois sobre isso.

Comment: Estava setando o bitmap no imageview num lugar errado, seu código funciona perfeitamente, obrigado por tudo cara!

Comment: @Morfina De nada, que bom que funcionou. Fico feliz em ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Como você disse, o erro está no argumento que está passando para o método `getMiniaturaImagem()`. Este método pede três argumentos: `ContentResolver cr, String imagePath, long imageId`. Neste caso, você passou o argumento `imageId` incorretamente. Ele tem que o ser o id referente a imagem que foi capturada, você passou um argumento errado, chamado `resultCode` que não corresponde ao id da Imagem relacionado com a miniatura.

Para obter o id da imagem, você terá que fazer uma consulta ao `MediaStore`, pelo menos é o único jeito que conheço, e isso deve ser feito em uma Thread fora da UI. Vou te passar um código onde é possível obter a miniatura da imagem corretamente. Outra coisa que eu ACHO que você confundiu, não tenho total certeza, mas acho que o método `ProcessImages.getOutputMediaFileUri(...)` não precisa ser executado fora da Thread UI, sendo assim, este trecho de código:

```
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // para usar fragment getActivity().getApplicationContext()
    uriImagem = ProcessImages.getOutputMediaFileUri(ProcessImages.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, ChecklistActivity.this);

    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriImagem);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Poderia ser executado na thread principal mesmo. Você pode verificar isso vendo se é necessário ou não fazendo uma pesquisa no google se algum código interno do método que eu criei precisa disso ou não.

Recomendo você estruturar seu código da seguinte forma agora:

```
/**
  * (ISTO é uma variável de instância) Contem o caminho e o nome do arquivo onde desejamos salvar a imagem. 
  * Usado principalmente para iniciar uma Intent.Action_View com esta URI. (GalleryApp)
  */
private Uri uriImagem = null;

public void onClickCamera(View v){
    // Cria uma intent para capturar uma imagem e retorna o controle para quem o chamou (NAO PRECISA DECLARAR PERMISSAO NO MANIFESTO PARA ACESSAR A CAMERA POIS O FAZEMOS VIA INTENT).
    Intent intent = new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    // Cria um arquivo para salvar a imagem.
    uriImagem = ProcessaImagens.getOutputMediaFileUri( ProcessaImagens.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, getActivity().getApplicationContext() );
    // Passa para intent um objeto URI contendo o caminho e o nome do arquivo onde desejamos salvar a imagem. Pegaremos atraves do parametro data do metodo onActivityResult().
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriImagem );
    // Inicia a intent para captura de imagem e espera pelo resultado.
    startActivityForResult( intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE );
}
```

Até então não usei Thread ou AsyncTask. Agora após a imagem ser capturada, vamos tratar o resultado em `onActivityResult` e obter a miniatura e COMPACTAR a imagem também.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
    // Se finalizou a activity em startForActivityResult.
    if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
        if ( requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE ) {
            new CarregaMiniaturaAsyncTask().execute();
        }
    }
    // Se cancelou a activity em startForActivityResult.
    else if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED ) {
        if ( requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE ) {
            // Usuario cancelou a captura da imagem.
            Log.d( getTag(), "Captura de imagem CANCELADA!" );
        }
    }
    // Se ocorreu algum erro na activity em startForActivityResult.
    else {
        // Captura da imagem falhou, avisa ao usuario.
        Toast.makeText( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "FALHA! A captura da imagem falhou!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        Log.e( getTag(), "FALHA! A captura da imagem falhou!" );
    }
}

    /**
     * Thread responsavel por carregar a miniatura de uma imagem.
     * Obtem o id da imamgem; Obtem o URI da imagem; Obtem o array de bytes da imagem; Obtem a miniatura da imagem.
     * Define o componente ImageView com a miniatura da imagem.
     */
    private class CarregaMiniaturaAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // Cria um novo cursor para obter o caminho do arquivo da imagem e sua miniatura.
        Cursor myCursor = null;

        // As colunas que queremos retornar.
        String[] projectionImage = {
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION};
        // Ira organizar a consulta por data em ordem decrescente.
        String imageSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC";

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        // Consulta as imagens armazenadas no sistema de arquivos.
        myCursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projectionImage, null, null, imageSort);

        long imageId = 0l; // Armazena o id da imagem.
        String imagePath = null; // Armazena o caminho para o arquivo da imagem.
        long imageDataTaken = 0l; // Armazena a data em que a imagem foi capturada da camera.
        long imageDataAdded = 0l; // Armazena a data em que a imagem foi adicionada ao MediaStore.
        int imageOrientation = 0; // Armazena a orientacao da imagem.

        // Obtem os dados da imagem
        try {
            myCursor.moveToFirst();
            imageId = myCursor.getLong(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID));
            imagePath = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
            imageDataTaken = myCursor.getLong(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN));
            imageDataAdded = myCursor.getLong(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED));
            imageOrientation = myCursor.getInt(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION));

            Log.d("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "Imagem id.: " + imageId);
            Log.d("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "Imagem path.: " + uriImagem.getPath());
            Log.d("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "Imagem data taken.: " + imageDataTaken);
            Log.d("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "Imagem data added.: " + imageDataAdded);
            Log.d("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "Imagem Orientation.: " + imageOrientation);

            // Obtem o URI da imagem em tamanho real para ser utilizado na visualizacao da imagem caso clique na miniatura.
            //uriImagem = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(imageId));
            Log.d("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "Imagem uri.: " + uriImagem.getPath());

            // Armazena o id da imagem para ser utilizado no recarregamento da imagem ao voltar da galeria do Android (Gallery App).
            long imagemId = imageId;

            List<Object> imagemCompactada = ProcessImages.compactarImagem(uriImagem.getPath());
            imagemBitmap = (Bitmap) imagemCompactada.get(0);
            byte[] imagemBytes = (byte[]) imagemCompactada.get(1);
            encoded = Base64.encodeBytes(imagemBytes, Base64.DONT_BREAK_LINES | Base64.URL_SAFE);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "A coluna nao existe", e);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e("PROCESSAMENTO DE IMAGENS", "Voce tentou acessar uma localizacao menor que zero ou maior que o tamanho da lista.", e);
        } finally {
            myCursor.close();
        }

        Log.i("uriImagemNova", uriImagem.getPath());

        return ProcessImages.getMiniaturaImagem(contentResolver, uriImagem.getPath(), imageId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        imagemBitmap = (Bitmap) result;
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(imagemBitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54268/discussion-on-answer-by-lucas-santos-gerando-bitmap-de-foto-tirada)